# Squirting noise while sleeping and other non-reproducible times?

Tags: gallbladder

I notice about once a week or so I hear a "squirting" sound somewhere within my body.  It is fairly loud and is enough to wake me while I am sleeping during early morning.  I've not found a real rhythm to the sound and it isn't even always while I am sleeping; sometimes it happens when I'm awake.

I've ignored this for years and my doctor visits have yielded no clarity on the issue.  I've also not found any answers with online research.  It would be nice if I could at least find a starting point for my research... Any idea of what this may be?

It almost sounds like my gall bladder vacating contents, but it sounds as though it is too loud to be down in my torso and thus I fear it may be something in my head or neck.